# I got the next error on my code, i need pass dato to csv: Mismatch between array dtype ('<U19941') and format specifier ('%.18e')

Tags: python, csv, mismatch

The next code is a part for the real, but in this part shows me on the screen 2 diferent vectors, y need pass that in CSV file,but shows me the next error on the line:
data = asarray(["{0}\n{1}\n".format(sentence,                       np.array(bag_vector))])

```
def generate_bow(allsentences, vocab):
list_vectores = []
for sentence in allsentences:
    sentence = sentence.split()
    bag_vector = np.zeros(len(vocab))
    for pal in sentence:
        for i, word in enumerate(vocab):
            if word == pal:
                bag_vector[i] += 1
    vector = asarray(bag_vector)
    print("{0}\n{1}\n".format(sentence,                         np.array(bag_vector)))
    # define data
    data = asarray(["{0}\n{1}\n".format(sentence,                       np.array(bag_vector))])
    # save to csv file
    savetxt('data.csv', data, delimiter=',')
```